# How to change internal grid margin in matplotlib scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to be able to add a margin before 0 on the Y axis.  to make the second figure below look like the first figure with whitespace before 0.  I have tried use_sticky-edges to false and have tried:

```
plt.margins(0.2,0.2)
```

That allows me to change the space on the X axis but the Y axis won't change.  How can I make this work?

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I need and how it normally does by default but for some reason it did not in the plot above:
[image]

How can I make this work?

Comment: Please create a [reprex].

Comment: I figured this out.  The problem comes from manually setting the ylim with plt.ylim.  I was able to just remove that setting and allow pyplot to set it.  That fixed the problem.

Comment: This shouldn't be closed. The docs of `plt.margins` don't make clear that this overrides xlim and ylim and is not applied on top of them. Hence, others could easily face the same issue.

Comment: @Joooeey Well, [the `plt.margins()+ docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.margins.html) tell *Specifying any margin changes only the autoscaling; for example, if xmargin is not None, then xmargin times the X data interval will be added to each end of that interval before it is used in autoscaling*.

Comment: @JohanC I read that too. I don't think it's clear. It doesn't mention axes limits, only auto-scaling. The relevant link to `autoscale_view` is buried in the docs of the `tight` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The problem comes from manually setting the ylim with plt.ylim. I was able to just remove that setting and allow pyplot to set it. That fixed the problem.